# Javascript recursive wrapping children (matryoshka doll)

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, nested

I'm having a difficult time trying to generate a text document based on a json document similar to the one below.

```
[{
    "title": "item 1",
    "nodes": [{
        "title": "item 1.1"
        "nodes": [{
            "title": "item 1.1.1"
        }, {
            "title": "item 1.1.2"
        }, {
            "title": "item 1.1.3",
            "nodes": [{
                "title": "item 1.1.3.1"
            }, {
                "title": "item 1.1.3.2"
            }, {
                "title": "item 1.1.3.3"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I have a simple recursive function that works fine however I want to generate something like a Matryoshka doll:

```
<branch title="item 1">
    <branch title="item 1.1">
        <item title="item 1.1.1"></item-end>
        <item title="item 1.1.2"></item-end>
        <branch title="1.1.3">
            <item title="1.1.3.1"></item-end>
            <item title="1.1.3.2"></item-end>
            <item title="1.1.3.3"></item-end>
        <branch-end>
    <branch-end>
<branch-end>
```

Each child should be wrapped by parent(s) with proper indention.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm using nodejs btw!

Comment: "Any ideas on how to solve this?" --- you use recursion to traverse the tree and as you progress - you put a proper indentation.

Comment: "I have a simple recursive function that works fine" --- how exactly "fine" is different from what you really need?

Comment: Just printing a single line works fine for each node; however when I want it to be wrapped by that which needs to be generated yet, I'm getting stuck.

Comment: I'm not even sure of how to keep track of the depth when it's really deep nested (for indention).

Comment: "I'm not even sure of how to keep track of the depth when it's really deep nested" --- pass it as a function parameter. Every time you invoke a function from itself - pass it as `depth + 1`

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this (uses two helpers for the html generation):

**Helpers.**

```
function pad(depth) {return '--'.repeat(depth);}

function makeBranch(title, body, depth) {
  return pad(depth) + '<branch title="'+ title + '">' +
    body + pad(depth) + '<branch-end>';
}

function makeItem(title, depth) {
  return pad(depth) + '<item title="'+ title + '"></item-end>';
}
```

**Definition.**

```
function gen(tree, depth) {
  if (!tree.nodes) {
    return makeItem(tree.title, depth);
  } else {
    return makeBranch(tree.title, tree.nodes.reduce(function(str, branch) {
      return str + gen(branch, depth + 1);
    }, ''), depth);
  }
}
```

**Usage.**

```
// Pass the root of the tree with depth = 0
gen(tree[0], 0);

//=> Output (formatted here for easier viewing):
"<branch title="item 1">
 --<branch title="item 1.1">
 ----<item title="item 1.1.1"></item-end>
 ----<item title="item 1.1.2"></item-end>
 ----<branch title="item 1.1.3">
 ------<item title="item 1.1.3.1"></item-end>
 ------<item title="item 1.1.3.2"></item-end>
 ------<item title="item 1.1.3.3"></item-end>
 ----<branch-end>
 --<branch-end>
 <branch-end>"
```

Thanks [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) for the correction.

Comment: I think OP's confusion is how to indent with the code.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for clarifying that. I had totally ignored that.

Comment: Yep. +1'd, but I personally would not put padding inside the `makeBranch`, `makeItem` items - it's not their responsibility and they should not know about padding at all.

Answer (score 0):

on my phone, so just some thought, no code.

the key is to flatten the tree structure into an array, in which every elements with an extra indention.

and you can flatten the tree with recursion easily. then all that left is to render the array